# VBA Instr function is not finding the substring from the position mentioned from all the sheets in workbook and deleting only from one Visible sheet

Tags: excel, vba

My Workbook has 3 sheets

Each sheet has set of rows.

Ex: Sheet 1 Name is A1 in that Column B - Cell B12 has the text [New Document]Please check before save

Ex: Sheet 2 Name is A2 in that Column B - Cell B7 has the text [New]

Ex: Sheet 3 Name is A3 in that Column B - Cell B6 has the text [New Document]Please check after save

Text to find across sheet to delete from entire workbook: [New Document]

Macro tried:

From Excel: Alt + F11

Insert -> Module

```
Option Explicit

Sub Master()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        RemoveRowsWithText ws
    Next ws
End Sub

Sub RemoveRowsWithText(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim r As Long
    For r = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
       If InStr(1, Cells(r, "B").Value, "[New Document]") =1 Then
            ws.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Expected Output:

After Running Macros

A1 in that Column B - Cell B12 has the text [New Document]Please check before save - Should be Deleted Successfully

A2 in that Column B - Cell B7 has the text [New] - Should not be Deleted

A3 in that Column B - Cell B6 has the text [New Document]Please check after save - Should be Deleted Successfully

Actual Output:

After Running Macros

A1 in that Column B - Cell B12 has the text [New Document]Please check before save - Is Deleted Successfully

A2 in that Column B - Cell B7 has the text [New] - is not Deleted and not sure whether goes to next sheet from A1

A3 in that Column B - Cell B6 has the text [New Document]Please check after save - is not deleted

Please help the corrections to be made to find the substring across sheet in entire workbook and delete all the occurrences from the across sheet in entire workbook.

Comment: Your loop is very inefficient. You can use `Range.AutoFilter` perhaps.

Comment: Sorry. My Bad. Wil explore on Range.AutoFilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below code. I made two changes.

1. Qualified All Objects to their parent (the unqualified `Cells` is probably why the third sheet did not delete).
2. Refactored the delete range method to make it faster

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Master()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        RemoveRowsWithText ws
    Next ws
End Sub

Sub RemoveRowsWithText(ws As Worksheet)

    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 to ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Row
       If InStr(1, ws.Cells(r, "B").Value, "[New Document]") > 0 Then
            Dim remove as Range
            If remove Is Nothing Then
                Set remove = ws.Cells(r,"B")
            Else
                Set remove = Union(remove,ws.Cells(r,"B"))
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If not remove Is Nothing
        remove.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time in correcting and helping with changes in detailed manner. Unable to upvote as Reputation Privilege is 1.